# PHPMailer adding attachments

Tags: php

I am using PHPMail from: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

and i want to be able to add attachments starting at the root path:

```
$email->AddAttachment( "../../admin/billing/invoices/5847884.pdf" , basename("../../admin/billing/invoices/5847884.pdf") );
```

but rather than using `../../` i want to be able to just use `/admin/billing...`

i have tried but its not attaching the attachments

Comment: Why would you use anything else, if this is working?

Comment: because the attachment names are coming from a database so they are not always going to be ../../ so in the database i want to be able to put the full path (/admin/attachment/1.pdf) or (/admin/folder/234.pdf)

Comment: Files should be attached as relative to current path or even better, absolute path. You should always know where your file on filesystem is.

Comment: As @Glavić says, you should always know where files are stored. The (full, absolute) path of directories like your uploads folder should be stored in a variable or constant so they can be used throughout your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As '/admin/folder/234.pdf' probably is not a valid absolute path in the filesystem, PHPMailer cannot find your file.

You have to add the base directory of your webspace:

```
$email->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/billing/invoices/5847884‌​.pdf');
```

Btw, you can leave out the second argument, PHPMailer will use basename() on your first argument to get the filename.

Comment: +1 probably the most cleanest solution possible, to further add though, you could add a define: `define( 'INVOICE_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/billing/invoices/' );` then `AddAttachment( INVOICE_DIR . 5847884.pdf' );`